# Update table rows based on values in a text file

Tags: postgresql, csv, sql-update

I have a Postgres table `publications` that has a `boolean` column `active`, and my task was to set all the `active` values to `FALSE`, so I did the following `copy` command to have a backup of the rows that have an `active` value of `TRUE`:

```sql
\copy (SELECT publication_id FROM publications WHERE active = TRUE)
to '~/active_publications.csv'
with csv
```

In the end, I got a CSV file that has all the `publication_id`s of the `active` rows. Then I ran the following command to set all the `active` values to `FALSE`:

```sql
UPDATE publications SET active = FALSE;
```

Now I need to go back in a reverse process: How can I use this file to set the `active` values back to `TRUE` for all the rows that have a `publication_id` in this CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to load the file with `COPY` into a temporary table and then use `UPDATE ... FROM` or `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT` to update your table.

Alternatively, you can use [`file_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) to define the file as a foreign table and `UPDATE` using that.